# Search and replace with term list?

Tags: search, replace, ultraedit

I wonder if there is a program that I can use with a list of terms I want to replace instead of take one by one.

Example

```
&Agrave;=À
&acirc;=â
&Acirc;=Â
&aring;=å
&Aring;=Å
&atilde;=ã
&Atilde;=Ã
```

Thank you in advance

I use **UltraEdit** and **powergrep atm**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UltraEdit** has 2 features for automating reformatting tasks: **macros** and **scripts**.

See UltraEdit forum topic [When to use Scripts over Macros](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=5337) for a brief overview of the differences.

### UltraEdit macro

An UltraEdit macro can be created by simply recording the replaces you manually do once on a file or you code them directly in **Edit/Create Macro** dialog.

A manual creation is done as follows:

1. Click in **UltraEdit** in menu **Macro** on menu item **Edit Macro**.
2. Click on button **New macro**.
3. Enter as *macro name* for example `ReplaceEntities`.
4. Uncheck macro property *Show cancel dialog for this macro*.
5. Let macro property *Continue if search string not found* checked.
6. Assign a hotkey or chord for quick execution by key if this is wanted for quick macro execution by key in future.
7. Click on button **OK**.
8. Back in **Edit/Create Macro**, there is now the new macro selected with 3 lines already present in edit field with the macro commands:
   `InsertMode`
   `ColumnModeOff`
   `HexOff`
9. Below those 3 macro commands must be added for this reformatting task the macro code lines posted below.
10. Click on button **Close** and confirm the question to update the macro with button **Yes**.

The macro is then ready for usage

- by assigned hotkey/chord,
- by double clicking on it in **Macro List** opened via **View - Views/Lists - Macro List** in case of not being already visible (docked or floating), or
- by using **Macro - Play Any/Multiple Times**.

Also **Macro - Play Again** can be very often used depending on which macro was last time executed.

The macro code required additionally to 3 standard commands already present in the dialog to replace in entire active file HTML entities is for example:

```
Top
UltraEditReOn
Find MatchCase "&Agrave;"
Replace All "À"
Find MatchCase "&acirc;"
Replace All "â"
Find MatchCase "&Acirc;"
Replace All "Â"
Find MatchCase "&aring;"
Replace All "å"
Find MatchCase "&Aring;"
Replace All "Å"
Find MatchCase "&atilde;"
Replace All "ã"
Find MatchCase "&Atilde;"
Replace All "Ã"
```

It is necessary to save this UE macro (without or with other UE macros) into a macro file by using **Macro - Save All**.

For using this macro (and other macros store in same macro file) later again, it is necessary to load the macro file using **Macro - Load**.

With **Macro - Set Auto Load** it is possible to select a macro file for being automatically loaded on startup of UltraEdit so that the macros in this macro file are available from beginning without an explicit loading of the macro file.

The macro properties can be also changed later by using **Macro - Delete Macro/Modify Properties**. Don't forget to use **Macro - Save All** after making a change to a macro code or its properties to save this change in macro file, too.

### UltraEdit script

UltraEdit scripts make use of the JavaScript core engine. An UltraEdit script is an ASCII/ANSI text file containing JavaScript core code with additional UltraEdit related scripting commands. This means an UltraEdit script can be written directly like any other text file and must not be edited in a dialog.

An UltraEdit script which makes exactly the same as the macro above would be:

```js
if (UltraEdit.document.length > 0)  // Is any file opened?
{
   // Define environment for this script.
   UltraEdit.insertMode();
   UltraEdit.columnModeOff();
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.hexOff();

   // Move caret to top of the active file.
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();

   // Define all parameters for several Replace All in entire active file.
   UltraEdit.ueReOn();
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.mode=0;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchCase=true;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchWord=false;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp=false;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchDown=true;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.preserveCase=false;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replaceAll=true;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replaceInAllOpen=false;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.selectText=false;
   // This property is only available since UE v14.10.
   if (typeof(UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn) == "boolean")
   {
      UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn=false;
   }

   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("&Agrave;","À");
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("&acirc;","â");
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("&Acirc;","Â");
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("&aring;","å");
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("&Aring;","Å");
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("&atilde;","ã");
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("&Atilde;","Ã");
}
```

Such an UltraEdit script should be saved with file extension **.js**, for example `ReplaceEntities.js`.

Once an UE script is saved, it can added via **Scripting - Scripts** to the **Script List** with adding a short description for the script and assigning a hotkey/chord to the script for quick execution by key.

The script is then ready for usage

- by assigned hotkey/chord,
- by double clicking on it in **Script List** opened via **View - Views/Lists - Script List** or **Scripting - Script List** in case of not being already visible (docked or floating), or
- by clicking on script file name in menu **Scripting**.

If an UE script is the active file AND it is written to run NOT on active document, the script can be also executed with **Scripting - Run Active Script**. But most scripts like the one above are written to run on active file and therefore requires adding the script file to the script list for execution.

The core objects and functions of JavaScript are not documented anywhere within UltraEdit although they can be also used in UltraEdit scripts. The documentation for the core features can be found on [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) site.

The additional scripting commands of UltraEdit are documented in help of UE on page with title [Scripting commands](http://www.ultraedit.com/help/article/scripting-commands-1245.html). There is additionally **View - Views/Lists - Tag List** containing the tag groups **UE/UES Script Commands** and also **UE/UES Macro Commands** for quick adding a scripting or macro command of UE in active file at current position of the caret.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my umlaut2html-Makro which does a few automated text-replacements. I guess it can serve as inspiration ;-)

```
// Lessons learned from Mofi ;-)
UltraEdit.ueReOn();
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.mode=0;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchCase=true;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchWord=false;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp=false;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchDown=true;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.preserveCase=false;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replaceAll=true;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replaceInAllOpen=false;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.selectText=false;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp=false;
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("ä","&auml;");    
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("ö","&ouml;");    
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("ü","&uuml;");    
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("Ä","&Auml;");    
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("Ö","&Ouml;");    
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("Ü","&Uuml;");    
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace("ß","&szlig;");
```

Save this into a .js-file anywhere you like (`MyDocuments\UE-Scripts` might be a good choice), then call Script > "Scripts..." and "Add", navigate to select that .js-file.

Comment: Awesome in which meny etc do I put into in Ultra edit?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I picked the wrong macro initially and forgot the instructions. Have now revised my anser, hopefully it will work for you :-)